# Add to Cart button is not Working on Product list Page in Magento

Tags: cart, magento-1.9

I have many products in my store (Magento). But in the list page configurable products are not adding to Cart. Googled lot and dig the code but no luck. Anyone can help me please?

http://www.homegennie.in/baby-care.html

Answer (score 0):

Always use firbug (firefox) or developer tools (chrome) to see what is happening communication-wise.

You can see outgoing requests, and their responses like this.

You have an error:

```
Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in <b>/home/homegennie/public_html/app/design/frontend/sm_market/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
```

Figure out what your error is, and you should be good to go.